# Append euro-sign to form textfield (zf2)

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to append a **€**-sign to my textfield, but it's not showing right. All I get is a �-sign. I've tried the following:

```
$(priceText).val("€ " + price + ",-");
$(priceText).val("&euro; " + price + ",-");
```

as well as `&#8364;` and `&#x20AC;`

But nothing's worked so far. Can anyone help? If more info is required, please ask, new to SO.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try with $(priceText).html("€ " + price + ",-");

Comment: @saty Then it doesn't show anything, just an empty textfield.

Comment: Try unicode value `\u20AC`.

Comment: Adding an answer so this issue can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably character encoding mismatch ([Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1372544/3639582)),

Use unicode value `\u20AC` for € (Euro)

```
$(priceText).val("\u20AC " + price + ",-");
```